# Token based authentication and authorization with ratpack and pac4j

Tags: java, security, spring-security, ratpack

I've used to securing rest api with spring security + spring session. This way allows me to auth client and generate his own session token which includes in every further request in header or cookie instead of login and password. I want to use this approach for ratpack + pac4j but I can't find any examples or documentation. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [official docs on pac4j integration](https://ratpack.io/manual/current/all.html#20%20pac4j) (unfortunately, it's scanty). Also you can use [official example project](https://github.com/pac4j/ratpack-pac4j-demo) on Github.

More precisely, use [CookieClient](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/master/pac4j-http/src/main/java/org/pac4j/http/client/direct/CookieClient.java) for cookie-based auth and [HeaderClient](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/master/pac4j-http/src/main/java/org/pac4j/http/client/direct/HeaderClient.java) for header-based auth from `pac4j-http` module. Example project doesn't show usage of this clients, but their use is similar to other client from `http` module, like `FormClient`.